# Opengl 2D performance tips

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm currently developing a Touhou-esque bullet hell shooter game. The screen will be absolutely filled with bullets (so instancing is what I want here), but I want this to work on older hardware, so I'm doing something along the lines of this at the moment, there are not colors, textures, etc. yet until I figure this out.

```
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, SQUARE_VERTICES);
for (int i = 0; i < info.centers.size(); i += 3) {
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(info.centers.get(i), info.centers.get(i + 1), info.centers.get(i + 2));
    glScalef(info.sizes.get(i), info.sizes.get(i + 1), info.sizes.get(i + 2));
    glDrawElements(GL_QUADS, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, SQUARE_INDICES);
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

Because I want this to work on old hardware I'm trying to avoid shaders and whatnot. The setup up there fails me on about 80 polygons. I'm looking to get at least a few hundred out of this. `info` is a struct which has all the goodies for rendering, nothing much to it besides a few vectors.

I'm pretty new to OpenGL, but I at least heard and tried out everything that can be done, not saying I'm good with it at all though. This game is a 2D game, I switched from SDL to Opengl because it would make for some fancier effects easier. Obviously SDL works differently, but I never had this problem using it.

It boils down to this, I'm clearly doing something wrong here, so how can I implement instancing for old hardware (OpenGL 1.x) correctly? Also, give me any tips for increasing performance.

Comment: Have you done any profiling using a tool like GDebugger? That will tell you the bottleneck.

Comment: Use as few draw calls as possible, try to put everything in one VA (do all the translations etc yourself on the CPU side).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Also, give me any tips for increasing performance.

If you're going to use **sprites**....

1. Load all sprites into single huge texture. If they don't fit, use several textures, but keep number of textures low - to avoid texture switching.
2. Switch textures and change OpenGL state as infrequently as possible. Ideally, you should set texture once, and draw everything you can with it.
3. Use texture fonts for text. FTGL font might look nice, but it can hit performance very hard with complex fonts.
4. Avoid alpha-blending when possible and use alpha-testing.
5. When alpha-blending, always use alpha-testing to reduce number of pixels you draw. When your texture has many pixels with alpha==0, cut them out with alpha-test.
6. Reduce number of very big sprites. Huge screen-aligned/pixel-aligne sprite (1024*1024) will drop FPS even on very good hardware.
7. Don't use non-power-of-2 sized textures. They (used to) produce huge performance drop on certain ATI cards.

> glTranslatef

For 2D **sprite-based**(that's important) game you could avoid matrices completely (with exception of camera/projection matrices, perhaps). I don't think that matrices will benefit you very much with 2D game.

With 2d game your main bottleneck will be GPU memory transfer speed - transferring data from texture to screen. So "use as little draw calls" and "put everything in VA" won't help you - you can kill performance with one sprite.

**However**, if you're going to use **vector** graphics (see [area2048](http://sourceforge.net/projects/area2048/)([youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ujN20CWZkC0)) or [rez](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ZNtZcqHUBI)) that does not use textures, then most of the advice above will not apply, and such game won't be very different from 3d game. In this case it'll be reasonable to use vertex arrays, vertex buffer objects or display lists (depends on what is available) and utilize matrix function - because your bottleneck will be vertex processing. You'll still have to minimize number of state switches.

Comment: Great tips! One question though: "Reduce number of very big sprites. Huge screen-aligned/pixel-aligned sprite (1024*1024) will drop FPS even on very good hardware." - What should I do, if I have a big, hi-res sprite to serve as static background for example and I don't want to do without it? Any alternatives?

Comment: As far as the bullets flooding the screen those will be vector graphics drawn from scratch. So what can I do to my current method to fix this? While waiting for an answer I switched to vertex arrays and didn't see any noticeable improvement, albeit it was rather quickly done. What exactly am I doing wrong? I'm taking a look at area2048 now. The game will mostly consist of vector graphics.

Comment: "Put everything in a VA" still applies with textured sprites. Don't believe it? Try it. A million draw calls kills performance real good.

Comment: @harold: if you have million draw calls in 2d shooter, then you have very serious game/engine design problem. Keep things real - you'll have to worry about "million draw calls" only if you ever get there. In reality your AI/Collision detection routines will die long before that.